# RRAS with DHCP when the IP pool is on a different subnet

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, dhcp, subnet, rras

I run a small business network and the last couple of days I have been setting up some equipment to add VPN capabilities to our network. I've got the following set up:

1. Windows 2008 R2 with RRAS - 172.22.200.50
2. Cisco RV082 router - 172.22.100.1 / 172.22.200.1

The Cisco router only support DHCP on a single class C network; 172.22.100.0/24. On the Cisco router I have set up an additional subnet; 172.22.200.0/24. The DHCP range is 172.22.100.200-254

When a PPTP connection comes in to the router, it is forwarded to my RRAS at 172.22.200.50. If I configure RRAS to assign IPs from a static pool on the 172.22.200.0/24 subnet everything works fine except the DNS suffix / search domain. However, if I set RRAS to use DHCP I am no longer able to contact any devices on the network. The IP I receive is on a different subnet (172.22.100.0/24).

Is it possible to still use DHCP as the method of ip assignment in RRAS, even when the IP adresses assigned are in a different subnet? If yes, what piece of configuration am I missing to fix the VPN connection issues mentioned in the paragraph above.

The reason I want RRAS with DHCP to work is because from what I have understood, this is the "only" way to hand out a DNS suffix to VPN clients.

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is working as designed, I did not quite get what do you need help about?

Comment: Sorry, I noticed it might have been a bit unclear what exactly I need help with. I have updated my question to hopefully make it more clear. In short, I want RRAS with DHCP to work (i.e. clients can actually contact devices on the network) even with the IP pool being on a different subnet (at the moment, clients are unable to communicate on the network).

Comment: I see. Are there any other devices in .200 subnet (except router and RRAS box?

Comment: Yes - about 3 physical devices and 5 virtual machines. I am using the .200 subnet for all my servers (they are all assigned static IPs).

Comment: Are subnets 100 and 200 on separate VLASNs? Also, can you run ROUTE PRINT on RRAS server (preferably with one client connected) and paste output.

Comment: I took a quick look at your router's manual. Perhaps adding another IP address (static, from subnet .100, without default gateway) to RRAS NIC would resolve the issue.